# Netlogo: Creating links to new neighbors

Tags: hyperlink, netlogo, digraphs

I try to generate a directed graph in Netlogo. There should only be one link between two nodes. I use the following code fragment:

---

```
breed [nodes node]
directed-link-breed [edges edge]

.
.
.

ask nodes
 [
    create-edges-to ((other nodes) with [not edge-neighbor? self])
 ]
```

---

It keeps creating two links (from and to) between the nodes. What's my error?

Thanks in advance!

Eric.

Comment: I think you want `myself` instead of `self`

Comment: Luke - you should do this as an answer so it can be accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems: first, using `self` in the context you are using it in checks if a node is connected to itself. You want `myself` here.

Second, because you are using directed links, if A is connected *to* B, B is considered a link neighbor of A, but not vice versa (because it's directed.) Think of `link-neighbor` as, "is there a way to get from turtle A to turtle B".

NetLogo offers in-link-neighbor? and out-link-neighbor? to address this. So you can do:

```
ask nodes [
    create-edges-to other turtles with [not out-edge-neighbor? myself]
]
```

Keep in mind that because this is run for each individual turtle, you will have a linear degree distribution. If that's what you're intending, then great! But it might not be. (edit: actually thinking this through, there's no way you wouldn't if you want all turtles to be connected by one directed link, so never mind.)

Comment: OK, thank you - It works with "myself". But the link direction seems to be irrelevant: (from the Netlogo Help) " <breed>-neighbor? turtle link-neighbor? Reports true if there is a link (either directed or undirected, incoming or outgoing) between turtle and the caller."

Comment: @Eric You're right, it's not because of link direction that `myself` works, but rather because the `other turtles` are the ones evaluated to see whether they have a link to the *asking* turtle that is indicated by `myself`. Pseudocode using `myself` is something like "create links with any turtles that are not already linked to me" as opposed to with `self` which would be "create links with any turtles that are not already linked to themselves"

Comment: Thank you Luke for the clarification.

Comment: Hi guys, I have found very useful this question and the answer. However I am still having an issue with my code. I leave here the link to question in case you might want to have a look and provide some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72178908/directed-undirected-using-nw-extension-in-netlogo